# How can I color a logo to make it bright at the top, and dark at the bottom?

Tags: color, gimp

I'm trying to create a logo with a background that is bright at the top, and darker at the bottom, like the following:

[image: [apple store logo]]

I tried some tools under "Colors" in GIMP but couldn't get what I wanted. I mainly edit at GIMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient

*(posting @AndrewH comment as community answer)*

Answer (score -2):

you can use dodge and burn system using curve or level[image]

Comment: anyway, this doesn't seem to answer the question - there is already an accepted answer, so if you're writing a new one it needs to be better than that. Check [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.